# Mocked Controller returning NULL

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using xUnit, and when I call the controller's method I am getting `null`. When I debugged, It is not going to `RemovePrimeNumbers` method but returning *null*.

Is there any reason why this occurs?

**Test Method**

```
public void ControllerTest()
{
    PrimeNumberViewModel returnObject = new PrimeNumberViewModel();
    returnObject.Result = new PrimeNumberModel();

    Mock<IPrimeNumberOperations> _mockService = new Mock<IPrimeNumberOperations>();
    var _controller = new PrimeNumberOperationsController(_mockService.Object) ;

    _mockService.Setup(x => x.RemovePrimeNumbers("Test123")).Returns(returnObject);

    var result = _controller.RemovePrimeNumbers("HAHAHA 2");

    Assert.Equal("HAHAHA 2", result);   
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet()]
public string RemovePrimeNumbers(string plainText)
{
    PrimeNumberViewModel result = _primeNumberService.RemovePrimeNumbers(plainText);
    return result.Result.removedPrimeNumbersText; // *result* is getting NULL 
}
```

Comment: If the controller is the subject under test, it should not be mocked. Mock the dependencies and inject them into an actual controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not returned the value, so you should return like below

```
var fakePrimeNumberViewModel = new PrimeNumberViewModel { new Result { removedPrimeNumbersText =  "HAHAHA 2"} }
_mockService.Setup(x => x.RemovePrimeNumbers("Test123")).Returns(fakePrimeNumberViewModel);
```

Besides, you should a new `Controller` instead of `Mock` it.

```
 var _controller = new PrimeNumberOperationsController(_mockService.Object);
```

And make sure that expected arguments given to the mock are the same used when exercising the test. For instance, in your example, the mock was setup to expect `"Test123"` but when the test is exercising it is given `"HAHAHA 2"` which will cause the mock to not behave as expected.

**Full code:**

```
public void ControllerTest()
{
    //Arrange
    string plainText = "Test123";
    string expected = "HAHAHA 2";
    Mock<IPrimeNumberOperations> _mockService = new Mock<IPrimeNumberOperations>();
    var fakePrimeNumberViewModel = new PrimeNumberViewModel { 
        new Result { removedPrimeNumbersText =  expected} 
    };
    _mockService
        .Setup(x => x.RemovePrimeNumbers(plainText))
        .Returns(fakePrimeNumberViewModel);

    var _controller = new PrimeNumberOperationsController(_mockService.Object);

    //Act
    var actual = _controller.RemovePrimeNumbers(plainText);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "Error message");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think you should wrap your SUT inside Mock
2. Make sure that your Setup returns a value
3. Make sure that the value returned from Setup is the same that you use to call the SUT method, otherwise, the Setup on `_primeNumberService.RemovePrimeNumbers` won't trigger and it will return null

Comment: I tried this also, But still, it is returning null, @Reed

Comment: Does your Setup(x => x.RemovePrimeNumbers("Test123")) matches what you call on the SUT _controller.RemovePrimeNumbers("HAHAHA 2"); ? It should be Test123 in both cases